# LaTex Question On Square Roots

Tags: math-mode

What am I doing wrong here?

```
\begin {align}
$\frac{3}{\sqrt{y}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}$}&=\frac{2}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}}$ \\
\frac{3}{a}-\frac{1}{b}&=\frac{2}{a+b} \\
$3(ab+b^2)-(a^2+ab)&=2ab$ \\
$3ab+3b^2-a^2-ab&=2ab$ \\
$3b^2&=a^2$ \\
$3(\sqrt{x})^2&=(\sqrt{y})^2$ \\
3x&=y \\
\frac{x}{y}&=\frac{1}{3}
\end {align}
```

this also does not work;

```
\begin {align*}
\frac{3}{$\sqrt{y}$}-\frac{1}{$\sqrt{x}$}&=\frac{2}{$\sqrt{x}$+$\sqrt{y}$} \\
\frac{3}{a}-\frac{1}{b}&=\frac{2}{a+b} \\
3(ab+$b^2$)-($a^2$+ab)&=2ab \\
3ab+3$b^2$-$a^2$-ab&=2ab \\
3$b^2$&=$a^2$ \\
3$($\sqrt{x}$)^2$&=$($\sqrt{y}$)^2$ \\
3x&=y \\
\frac{x}{y}&=\frac{1}{3}
\end {align*}
```

Comment: You do not want those $ signs inside the align environment, which already puts you in math mode. And, for the future, when you have a question post the smallest possible complete document that illustrates your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, remove the `$` secondly encapsulate your equation in an `equation` environemt with `\begin{equation}` and `\end{equation}`. Furthermore, I would use `\begin{aligned}` instead of `\end{align}`. That should work.

### Code after editing

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\frac{3}{\sqrt{y}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}&=\frac{2}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}} \\
\frac{3}{a}-\frac{1}{b}&=\frac{2}{a+b} \\
3(ab+b^2)-(a^2+ab)&=2ab \\
3ab+3b^2-a^2-ab&=2ab \\
3b^2&=a^2 \\
3(\sqrt{x})^2&=(\sqrt{y})^2 \\
3x&=y \\
\frac{x}{y}&=\frac{1}{3}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

### Output

[image: equation-output]